# How to make discord.py bot add scorpius sign as well as mod role?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried this code-

```
    @client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)     
async def mod(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, nickname):
    nickname = '♏' + user.name
    await client.change_nickname(user, nickname)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name='Moderator')
    await client.add_roles(ctx.message.mentions[0], role)
    await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
```

But facing error. If you have any idea then please help me

Comment: rip i got error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/vucetirane.py check it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is arising because you're not invoking the command with a `nickname`.  Your code doesn't actually use the `nickname` that gets passed, so you can just change the coroutine signature to

```
async def mod(ctx, user: discord.Member):
```